# C# ssh connection to HP switches (bypassing "more")

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

I'd like to use ssh to download information from a switch. The command on Switch will display the test data broken into parts and I must press a space. Using Open SSH, it save a piece of text and "MORE" appears at the end. Could someone suggest me an idea how to download all data in c#, without press a space?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the SSH nuget to remote into the switch. https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET

To disable line breaks, we can make use of the command `no paging` for your HP switch as per [documentation stated here](https://www.arubanetworks.com/techdocs/ArubaOS_61/ArubaOS_61_CLI/paging.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Man asks for help downloading the configs from his HP switch and you point him to a new SSH client?  WOW. Mateusz... have you tried simply copying the config to a TFTP server?  Windows has a slew of tftp servers that are easy to setup.  From the command line you'd do something like this:

```
copy running-config tftp 172.16.1.41 Procurve5412zl_Bld2130
```

The command breaks down into copying what file; Running, startup, flash, etc..  In our case use tftp (can also save to a USB drive connected to the switch) then the Name or IP of your TFTP server finally the destination name for the file.

Pretty simple stuff.  Hope that's what you were looking for.